# My "Mix Shader" node doesn't have a "Fac" input socket

Tags: shaders

I have seen some videos, but I noticed that there is a problem, is there no "fac" command on Mix Shaders?

[image]

i can't find it... (blender is in italian: "somma ombreggiature" ==> "mix shaders")

[image]

Comment: It looks like that's an Add Shader.  (Somma = sum?)

Answer (score 3):

There is a *Mix Shader* node with a *fac* input and an *Add Shader* node with only 2 *shader* inputs, they are not the same node :

[image]

Or in Italian

[image]

Comment: thank you guys!